# How to add a Deployable container to my class path?

Tags: java, junit, jboss

I got a TestRunner class that runs all my tests from jUnit AllTests(TestSuite), which contains all the tests (UTests.java) that are needed for my application...

```
public class TestRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(AllTests.class);

      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }

      System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
   }
}


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ UTests.class })
public class AllTests {

}

@Test public void testAddStudent() { 
StudentBean sb = new StudentBean();
Student s1 = new Student(4, "Ognjen", "Car");
System.out.println(s1.toString());

Boolean s = sb.addStudent(s1); 
System.out.println(s1);

assert (s == true); 
// fail("Not yet implemented");
}
```

StudentBean.java

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Override
public Boolean addStudent(Student s) {
try{
    Student s1 = new Student(10,"asd", "asd"); //for testing...later I ll delete it
    em.persist(s);
    em.flush();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

    return true;
}
```

Once I run the TestRunner class, there are 2 errors, that appear to be one....

1st At the console:

```
test.UTests: DeploymentScenario contains a target (_DEFAULT_) not matching any defined Container in the registry.
Please include at least 1 Deployable Container on your Classpath.
```

false

2nd At the JUnit console:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.ValidationException: DeploymentScenario contains a target (_DEFAULT_) not matching any defined Container in the registry.
Please include at least 1 Deployable Container on your Classpath.
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.DeploymentGenerator.throwNoContainerFound(DeploymentGenerator.java:250)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.DeploymentGenerator.throwTargetNotFoundValidationException(DeploymentGenerator.java:243)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.DeploymentGenerator.validate(DeploymentGenerator.java:102)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.DeploymentGenerator.generateDeployment(DeploymentGenerator.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:87)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:202)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:431)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:219)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The error is asking to add a Deployable container to my class path, and I have no idea how to do it...

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add some dependencies in your pom. It would look like that:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Source: http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_pt/

Answer (score -1):

Add the following dependencies:

```
     <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR9</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.4</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

then Right-click on the project go to properties then click on maven under active maven profile paste this "arquillian-weld-ee-embedded".
if you are using some other conatiner use that in maven active profile.